# SYSVOL policy folder access denied

Tags: permissions, group-policy, sysvol

In my C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain\Policies I have two foldes I can't open ... gets "Access denied"...

[image]

If I try to change perssion I get the message, that I do not have permission:

[image]

From my backup, I can see the two folders are empty.

These two "access denied" folders make my DFS Replication fails.

How do I get rid of these two folders?

Comment: Have you tried changing the owner of those two folders? You can do this by going Security tab>advanced and then in the top you will see the owner displayed and a button to "CHANGE". Select your user account. You may need to re-enter the folder for the permissions to take effect.

Comment: Are you a domain admin ? Depends on the GPO rights. You can use Get-GPO -Guid <GUID> -Domain "mydomain.contoso.com" to find the related GPO and investigate on the GPO Management console

Comment: @SleepyMan ... yes, it's the same ... it shows me the same "permission" dialog.

Comment: @Swisstone ... yes I am. Thanks - I will try it.

Comment: @Swisstone ... the result is ... Get-GPO : A GPO with ID {6de5f64f-793a-4fbb-b495-b56eff167203} was not found in the x.local domain.